# Sticky footer flickers on changing position from fixed to relative

Tags: jquery, sticky, sticky-footer

On scrolling the body, the **footer** should push the **footer menu** upwards.

I have implemented it using the below code, but upon scrolling, the footer menu flickers because the extra height gets added to the document.

How to fix this issue?

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
 let footer         = $( '#footer' );
 let secondary_menu = $( '.menu-for-mobile' );

 $( window ).scroll( function() {
  if ( ( $( this ).scrollTop() + $( this ).height() ) >= footer.offset().top ) {
   if ( ! footer.hasClass( 'make-relative' ) ) {
    footer.addClass( 'make-relative' );
    secondary_menu.addClass( 'make-relative' );
   }
  } else {
   if ( footer.hasClass( 'make-relative' ) ) {
    footer.removeClass( 'make-relative' );
    secondary_menu.removeClass( 'make-relative' );
   }
  }
 });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 200vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.menu-for-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.make-relative {
 position: relative;
}

#footer {
  padding: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
</div>
<div class="menu-for-mobile">
  Footer Menu
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Depending on your browser support, using `position: sticky;` might make more sense: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: @AlanShortis it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by wrapping your footer menu in another div, and padding it the height of the menu. That way, the height already exists in the document, and there will be no flicker.

Alternatively if you don't know the height of the menu, you could add the padding dynamically.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I'm a bit confused on how to implement it. Can you modify it in my code so that I can see how to?